missing max log history settings
I am struggling to get a solution to keep the log history in a limited number of files.
There is no something like:
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-history=20

If I don't want more than 20 log files in the directory, how can I do that?
Note that:
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=5

just keep up to 5 files with the same suffix, but it leaves the files for time being accumulating storage day by day.
Is there any solution for this use case?
cheers,

Please open an issue asking for this

Thank you. Yes I opened a new feature already.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/41122
